# Find the best integer value possible using o- and O-notation for some series.

Tags: numerical-methods

**a**. Consider the series
\begin{equation}
e^{\tan(x)}=1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}+\frac{3x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{9x^{4}}{4!}+\dots\qquad (|x|\leq\pi/2)
\end{equation}
Retaining three terms in the series, estimate the remaining series using o-notation with the best integer value possible, as $x\to 0$.

**b**. Repeat the same problem using O-notation and the series
\begin{equation}
\ln(\tan(x))=\ln(x)+\frac{x^{2}}{3}+\frac{7x^{4}}{90}+\frac{62x^{6}}{2835}+\dots\qquad (0<|x|<\pi/2).
\end{equation}

> In general, we write  \begin{equation} f(x)=O(g(x))\qquad (x\to x^{*})
> \end{equation} when there is a constant C and a neighborhood of
>   $x^{*}$ such that $\left | f(x) \right |\leq C\left | g(x) \right |$
>   in that neighborhood. Similarly,  \begin{equation} f(x)=o(g(x))\qquad (x\to x^{*})  \end{equation} means that $\lim_{x\to
> > x^{*}}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.
>
> (Source: Numerical Analysis: Mathematics of Scientific Computing)

*My answer:* We start with **a**, we get
\begin{equation}
e^{\tan(x)}-\left (1+x+\frac{x^{2}}{2!}  \right )=\frac{3x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{9x^{4}}{4!}+\dots=o(x^{n})
\end{equation}
which is
\begin{equation}
\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{3x^{3}}{3!}+\frac{9x^{4}}{4!}+\dots}{x^{n}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{3x^{3-n}}{3!}+\frac{9x^{4-n}}{4!}+\dots=0
\end{equation}
Now I'm stuck. I've no idea what I'm going to do the next step. I'd also be appreciated if you explain me about the other problem (**b**), please.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

> $f(x)=o(g(x))$ iff $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$.

Comment: Why repeat something already in the question and name it a "hint", when it is not particularly enlightening?